# language name declaration - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, store-view, magento-2.0.1

I am looking for **where the locale name declared in language pack?**

We can see the list of language in admin or using command line

```
Store > Configuration > General > Locale Option
```

or

```
bin/magento info:language:list
```

I have searched in `/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/language-de_de` (composer.json, language.xml, registration.php) but unable to find the exact name of the locale like listed in admin(**German (Germany)**).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can get all language declaration list from **`vendor`** folder **`Magento\Framework\Locale\Config.php`** file.

you can check here from above class,

```
protected $_allowedLocales = [
        'af_ZA', /*Afrikaans (South Africa)*/
        'ar_DZ', /*Arabic (Algeria)*/
        'ar_EG', /*Arabic (Egypt)*/
        'ar_KW', /*Arabic (Kuwait)*/
        'ar_MA', /*Arabic (Morocco)*/
        'ar_SA', /*Arabic (Saudi Arabia)*/
        'az_Latn_AZ', /*Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)*/
        'be_BY', /*Belarusian (Belarus)*/
        'bg_BG', /*Bulgarian (Bulgaria)*/
        'bn_BD', /*Bengali (Bangladesh)*/
        'bs_Latn_BA', /*Bosnian (Bosnia)*/
        'ca_ES', /*Catalan (Catalonia)*/
        'cs_CZ', /*Czech (Czech Republic)*/
        'cy_GB', /*Welsh (United Kingdom)*/
        'da_DK', /*Danish (Denmark)*/
        'de_AT', /*German (Austria)*/
        'de_CH', /*German (Switzerland)*/
        'de_DE', /*German (Germany)*/
        'el_GR', /*Greek (Greece)*/
        'en_AU', /*English (Australian)*/
        'en_CA', /*English (Canadian)*/
        'en_GB', /*English (United Kingdom)*/
        'en_NZ', /*English (New Zealand)*/
        'en_US', /*English (United States)*/
        'es_AR', /*Spanish (Argentina)*/
        'es_CO', /*Spanish (Colombia)*/
        'es_PA', /*Spanish (Panama)*/
        'gl_ES', /*Galician (Galician)*/
        'es_CR', /*Spanish (Costa Rica)*/
        'es_ES', /*Spanish (Spain)*/
        'es_MX', /*Spanish (Mexico)*/
        'eu_ES', /*Basque (Basque)*/
        'es_PE', /*Spanish (Peru)*/
        'et_EE', /*Estonian (Estonia)*/
        'fa_IR', /*Persian (Iran)*/
        'fi_FI', /*Finnish (Finland)*/
        'fil_PH', /*Filipino (Philippines)*/
        'fr_CA', /*French (Canada)*/
        'fr_FR', /*French (France)*/
        'gu_IN', /*Gujarati (India)*/
        'he_IL', /*Hebrew (Israel)*/
        'hi_IN', /*Hindi (India)*/
        'hr_HR', /*Croatian (Croatia)*/
        'hu_HU', /*Hungarian (Hungary)*/
        'id_ID', /*Indonesian (Indonesia)*/
        'is_IS', /*Icelandic (Iceland)*/
        'it_CH', /*Italian (Switzerland)*/
        'it_IT', /*Italian (Italy)*/
        'ja_JP', /*Japanese (Japan)*/
        'ka_GE', /*Georgian (Georgia)*/
        'km_KH', /*Khmer (Cambodia)*/
        'ko_KR', /*Korean (South Korea)*/
        'lo_LA', /*Lao (Laos)*/
        'lt_LT', /*Lithuanian (Lithuania)*/
        'lv_LV', /*Latvian (Latvia)*/
        'mk_MK', /*Macedonian (Macedonia)*/
        'mn_Cyrl_MN', /*Mongolian (Mongolia)*/
        'ms_Latn_MY', /*Malaysian (Malaysia)*/
        'nl_NL', /*Dutch (Netherlands)*/
        'nb_NO', /*Norwegian BokmГ_l (Norway)*/
        'nn_NO', /*Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)*/
        'pl_PL', /*Polish (Poland)*/
        'pt_BR', /*Portuguese (Brazil)*/
        'pt_PT', /*Portuguese (Portugal)*/
        'ro_RO', /*Romanian (Romania)*/
        'ru_RU', /*Russian (Russia)*/
        'sk_SK', /*Slovak (Slovakia)*/
        'sl_SI', /*Slovenian (Slovenia)*/
        'sq_AL', /*Albanian (Albania)*/
        'sr_Cyrl_RS', /*Serbian (Serbia)*/
        'sv_SE', /*Swedish (Sweden)*/
        'sw_KE', /*Swahili (Kenya)*/
        'th_TH', /*Thai (Thailand)*/
        'tr_TR', /*Turkish (Turkey)*/
        'uk_UA', /*Ukrainian (Ukraine)*/
        'vi_VN', /*Vietnamese (Vietnam)*/
        'zh_Hans_CN', /*Chinese (China)*/
        'zh_Hant_HK', /*Chinese (Hong Kong SAR)*/
        'zh_Hant_TW', /*Chinese (Taiwan)*/
        'es_CL', /*Spanich (Chile)*/
        'lo_LA', /*Laotian*/
        'es_VE', /*Spanish (Venezuela)*/
        'en_IE', /*English (Ireland)*/
    ];
```

Comment: great! If I create new locale te_TE, I need to declare here? or it will collect automatically from language package.

Comment: i havent try for new language but magento admin core declaration list are comes from here.

Comment: I have tried with add new locale but it will not reflected in admin, I think it will collect somewhere else (like app/etc/config.php) however I am not sure, let we wait what others think.